# How to check if map works in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dictionary

I have a series of identical mysql tables in a list of databases as follows

```
A_1.table
A_2.table
A_3.table
```

the tables are accesssed  by means of a series of ip addresses as follows

```
 IP1, IP2, IP3.
```

The mysql database table names are stored as tablelist and the ip addresses are stored in list called hostlist
These tables are stored in mysql database with the following credentials

```
username=x
password=pw
port=1234
```

I have created the following code

```
  def proc(db, hostname):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(user=x, password=pw,
                          host=hostname,
                          database=db, port=1234)
     db_cursor = con.cursor()
     db_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
     table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
     df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
     print(df.head(1))
con.close()
```

Next I have applied the above code to both lists as follows.

```
  a=map(proc, tablelist, hostlist)
```

The code seems to work as there are no errors. How do I test if the map command works. In R We get True as an output to let us know if map has worked

Comment: You proc must be the udf which you can control. mapping is just mapping the attributes to the function. It will fail if your attributes are erroneous or your udf is not able to consume the attributes passed as arguments to the udf. If mapping was successful then you will have a valid list otherwise control your udf to return something unusual values if something went wrong and check the list after executing the map. Hope it all makes sense.

Comment: The variables are left generic so that the values are read correctly